# Spaceship movie/TV-show where the villain appears as electric spark

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I watched this English movie or TV show during 1980s in my childhood. The story was in a spaceship. Several people was in the spaceship, among whom the main character was a lady.

The villain appears as electric sparks near the ceiling of a room in the ship. He appears only when a lady remains alone. He then converts to a man in long black robe. He tries to penetrate his metallic long fingernail into her neck. The lady was so scared and tried to escape. One day he was successful to penetrate. Then her mind was converted and inclined to him. Then he took her away with a small space shuttle detached from the main spaceship.

He was driving the shuttle but suddenly he started to be melted down and finally destroyed. Then the lady went back to the main spaceship and met her friends.

Answer (score 3):

"Buck Rogers in the 25th Century"(1979-1981 TV series)

Episode 12 from the 2nd season: Space Vampire?

I remember the villain in this one had long, black fingernails (metallic?), and he could turn into a small cloud of lights. He was a vampire creature that Buck discovers is known as a Vorvon. I also remember the Vorvon escaping in a shuttle craft with a vampirized Wilma, whose mind has been taken over by the Vorvon. When they are escaping, they get too close to the sun, and the Vorvon disintegrates but Wilma survives and retains her humanity. She makes it back to the space station and her friends. Below is a short trailer of this episode from YouTube.

Comment: I immediately thought of this episode as well.

Comment: This reminds me, I need to buy this series on DVD. It was super cheezy, but brings back so many good memories.

Comment: OMG......... Thanks a lot for so quick response. Finally I got the answer. I searched it days after days. Thanks...